# $add value in mongo datatabase

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have Mongo database which contain documents like these:

```
{"_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "price" : "10", "fee" : 2 },
{"_id" : 2, "item" : "efc", "price" : "NAN", "fee" : 2 },
{"_id" : 2, "item" : "efc", "price" : "20", "fee" : 2 },
```

I would like to calculate all price in my database , using this code

```
db.logss.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$ApplicationName",
            "count": {
                $sum: {'$toInt': '$RcvBytes'}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {"count": -1}
    },
    {
        $limit: 10
    }
]);
```

I am converting the price value to int as it is stored in database as  string , but because my database contain `NAN` Values , I get

> "errmsg" : "Failed to parse number 'NAN' in $convert with no onError value: Bad digit \"N\" while parsing NAN",

so I want to calculate all values where Price not "NAN" 
I tried a lot without success

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to convert the `NaN` values to 0 to avoid counting them:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$ApplicationName",
        "count": {
            $sum: {$toInt: {$cond: [{$eq: [NaN, "$RcvBytes"]}, '0', '$RcvBytes']}}
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could just match only relevant documents before the `$group` stage by adding this `$match` phase:

```
{
    $match: {
        RcvBytes: {$ne: NaN}
    }
}
```

- If the `NaN` values are saved as string just replace it with `'NaN'` to match the value.